# PHP: Copy file to php-created-directory in Ubuntu didn't work

Tags: php, file, ubuntu, directory, copy

I have an ubuntu server. My objective is to create a directory within the root directory for the ftp user (suresh, say) copy some files from the latter to the newly created directory.

**The problem is, I am able to create new directory, but when I try to copy files within this directory, it wont work.**

I tested the script to copy file locally (in the root directory), it works. I changed the permission of the newly created directory to 0777, it works, but not for 0775. I tried two examples of copy. Both work.

The owner user/group of the newly created directory is www-data (its a ubuntu server with root access). The permission is 755 for the directory. Changing the owner to the ftp user suresh didn't make it either.

The following is the php I used:

```
<?php
//To create directory/subdirectory recursively

$mode = 0775; 
mkdir("./directory/subdirectory", $mode, TRUE);

//Source and destination
$source = "index.php";
$dest = "directory/index.php"

//Copy function first version
function stream_copy($src, $dest) 
    {
        $fsrc = fopen($src,'r');
        $fdest = fopen($dest,'w+');
        $len = stream_copy_to_stream($fsrc,$fdest); 
        fclose($fsrc);
        fclose($fdest);
        return $len; 
} 

if (!stream_copy($source,$dest)){
    echo "File stream copy to directory not successful! <br />";
} else {
    echo "Check the directory for index file! <br />";
}

//And I always get the "...not successful" output!

//Copy function second version
function copyemz($file1,$file2){
    $contentx =@file_get_contents($file1); 
    $openedfile = fopen($file2, "w"); 
    fwrite($openedfile, $contentx); 
    fclose($openedfile); 
    if ($contentx === FALSE) { 
    $status=false; 
} else $status=true;

    return $status; 
}

if (!copyemz($source,$dest)){
    echo "File copy to directory not successful <br />";
} else {
    echo "Check the directory for index!<br />";
}

//The same result for this either!

?>
```

Finally I tried the shell_exec and same result for this as well! All these work with the conditions set a

Can anyone explain me what is happening or what I am missing!

The user for ftp (suresh) is a group-member of www-data, and vice-versa. (Just if it helps! Tried otherwise also.)

Answer (score 0):

You create "./directory/subdirectory" but you copy to "directory/". So are you sure that "direcotry" is also owned by www-data?

Comment: Yes. The "directory" is owned by www-data user and group. Further, "./directory" and "directory" within the current directory mean the same. So, it does not matter. Any suggestions now?